# Inserting text file words into AVL

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I am stuck on a small part of my assignment where I need to basically insert the data from the .txt file (which are just random words) and add them to my AVL tree as data.

I will show you the code I have now which doesn't work obviously, but need a few tips on how to read the file and insert it into the AVL tree as data.

Where it says [ newItem.key = (file); ] the name I type in for the .txt shows up in the AVL tree perfectly (I know this because yes its just reading my string I made), but I need the entire .txt document full of words to be placed in there as I read it not the title. I hope this makes sense and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the file one word at a time:

```
while (myfile) {
  std::string word;
  myfile >> word;
  newItem.key = word;
  tree.AVL_Insert(newItem);
}
```